# Is it in poor form to delete and repost a poorly-received meta post after a major edit?

Tags: discussion, meta

Some time ago I made a post (a question) here on meta, wherein I tried to be "cute" and "funny" and consequentially completely failed to communicate my idea. The post was poorly received and for good reason. The score on it is something like -24/+16. Even without the score feedback, rereading the post now it's obvious that it failed to make the point I wanted to make.

I recently revisited it and made a major edit, removing my silliness, rewriting the post, and hopefully clearly stating the idea in a more detailed and serious manner.

Part of me wants to just delete the question and repost to start fresh. I'm not necessarily convinced the edited version will be well-received either, and that's OK, but I do feel like a fresh start would be appropriate.

The reason I feel a fresh start would be appropriate is because of the presumption that most people, after reading a question on meta and forming an opinion, don't go back and monitor it for edits and change their opinions accordingly. In my case, the post is actually a bit different now.

The motivation here is bringing a major edit to the attention of folks who already read the first version, long after the post was posted (it's not  getting a lot of new views), so that they can reevaluate their opinion, noting that their new opinion may very well still be negative and that that's OK.

So my question is: Given all that, is it in poor form for me to delete and repost the question? Should I just accept that I blew my chance to make a point and call it a loss? Or would this be justified?

Also, if it is not acceptable, what other things can I do to draw attention to the edit or encourage folks to reevaluate their opinions?

I am not linking to my specific post because I'm looking for a general opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a good rule of thumb: if your edit turns existing responses into nonsense, post a new question instead. If it doesn't, it's probably not a new question.

Most of the time, you probably can't delete the question anyway if folks have been responding to it... Unless they responded entirely in comments. I wouldn't bother.

Comment: And [Kevin B's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345891) as well.

Answer (score 12):

I'd have to go with, *Yes*, that's poor form for the same reason it's poor form to do so on main. Yes, meta is different, but in this case the problems with doing so are the same.

One thing that IS different with meta over main is that meta not only has questions, but also feature requests and discussions. With the latter two of those, it may make more sense to instead post an answer to the question rather than making such a major edit to the question itself so that the ideas in the new answer can be voted on separately from the ideas in the question.

For meta *questions* (such as this one) though... I can't think of a situation where a major edit would change the way people perceive the question without it turning the question from one thing to another. In that situation a delete → repost may make more sense, if the new question is significantly different from the old to the point where you are essentially asking a new question and deleting an old inactive question that is unrelated.